# How can I geocode (get latitudes and longitudes) millions of addresses?

Tags: database, dataset, geocoding

I have a dataset with millions of U.S. addresses. I would like to geocode this dataset. Yahoo had an API with the most generous rate limit (50K per day, still too low for my purposes), but this is defunct. I don't think any API, unless I can do over 100K requests per day, will suit my needs.

Is there any simple-to-configure software I can download to do this from my own computer?

In particular, to those who have experience with it, will
http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#setup
suit my needs?

Comment: I'd start by testing a representative sample of the addresses on their site. Compare to google's results. If their data looks good, go for it!

Answer (score 0):

Would an API that supports millions of requests per day suit your needs?

There are few services which do this. In particular, [LiveAddress](http://smartystreets.com/products) by SmartyStreets can handle that kind of load and is actually built for it. You can [upload files](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-lists) (like Excel or CSV, etc, zipped up esp. if you have that many) or [query the API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) (each request can support 100 addresses).

So while the program doesn't get downloaded to your computer, it will actually be faster than a localized, in-house solution, because it scales up and when the load is high. LiveAddress is geo-distributed and is powered by RAM drive servers which spin up more nodes when there's lots of work to do. LiveAddress is known for [handling millions of addresses quickly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21397/5599) (like in a few hours).

I work at SmartyStreets. We kind of dare you to see how fast you can legitimately query the API or upload and process all your lists. There's [plenty of sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples) for the API or you can (programmatically or manually) upload your list files for batch geocoding.

Comment: Way out of my price range, but thank you.